The latest approach for feature dimenesion reduction
I have a feature matrix with 1200 rows and 18930 columns. The matrix is sparse and the original paper has used a stacked denoising autoencoder for dimensionality reduction. Since I want to enhance the results, which newly published dimensionality reduction technique would be suiatable for my case?

What kind of data is it? Can you hyperlink the paper in your question?

@nwaldo The values in the matrix represent term frequency of some genes name in a text hence they are continuous.

If your data is discrete, then you could try deep matrix factorization(DeepMF) which is most commonly used on collaborative filtering dataset(recommender systems).
https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.00380

Is this approach applicable to continuous data, too?
